# angular access module scope from factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm pretty new to angular.

What I want is that when a factory method is called from outside, the method should update the modules scope data, like this:

```
fileList.controller('FileListController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.device = {};
    $scope.files = [];
    $scope.isDeviceDefined = function () {
        return typeof $scope.device === 'object' && $scope.device !== null && $scope.device.hasOwnProperty('label');
    };
}]);

fileList.factory('deviceFiles', ['$scope', 'files', function ($scope, files) {
    return {
        setFilesForDevice: function (device) {
            $scope.device = device;
            $scope.files = files.getFilesFromDevice(device.label);
        }
    };
}]);
```

But it says, that the $scope is a unknown provider. Is there a other way, that the modules data can be updated? `setFilesForDevice` is a method that is called by clicking a button inside a different controllers template.

Comment: `$scope` technically is *local* to the controller, i.e. there is no Angular service providing it; the view subsystem provides it to each controller it instantiates. So no, services **cannot have the scope injected** to them. And they shouldn't, conceptually it is wrong to have the service layer depending on the view. What can you do? (1) have the service return an object and bind that to the scope (2) pass the scope to the service method as argument [(3) possibly others]. I would go for (1).

Comment: Scopes are created by / for directives. Controllers are associated with directives, that's why they can be given access to their scopes. Services have no connection to directives. Ergo they have no business with scopes.

Comment: Then how could I possibly update the $scope values when the deviceFiles factory method is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a bit different approach here. First, you get your device id in the controller via $routeParams.device.

Then you create a service that would be injectable into FileListController and deliver information about files, i.e.

```
fileList.controller('FileListController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'deviceFilesService', function ($scope, $routeParams, deviceFilesService) {
    $scope.device = $routeParams.device;
    $scope.files = deviceFilesService.getFilesForDevice($routeParams.device);
}]);

fileList.service('deviceFilesService', ['files', function (files) {
    this.getFilesForDevice = function (device) {
        // Code to look up list of files the the device
    };
}]);
```